# SQL CHECK constraint on VARCHAR and MEMO fields

Tags: sql, ms-access, odbc, oledb

Using `MS Access` with ODBC or OleDB (and C#). The `MS Access` version is old, probably Access 97.

Have attempted the following syntaxes to ensure the "Description" field cannot be zero-length:

- CREATE TABLE TestTable ([Description] Memo CHECK ( LEN(Description) > 0 ));
- CREATE TABLE TestTable ([Description] Memo CHECK ConstraintName ( LEN(Description) > 0 ));
- CREATE TABLE TestTable ([Description] Memo CHECK ( DATALENGTH(Description) > 0 ));
- CREATE TABLE TestTable ([Description] Memo CHECK ConstraintName ( DATALENGTH(Description) > 0 ));

Each one throws a `Syntax error in field definition` exception.

What is the correct syntax for checking the length of `VARCHAR` or `MEMO` fields?

Comment: I suspect check constraints are not supported in Access '97 (Jet 3.5) databases.  Many Access DDL features were not added until Jet 4.0.  My guess is check constraints are one of those features.

Comment: Can you convert your db or import its data into a newer Access db format?  With an ACCDB in Access 2010, I created the table and then added the constraint with an `ALTER TABLE`: `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "ALTER TABLE TestTable ADD CONSTRAINT ConstraintName CHECK (LEN([Description]) > 0);"`

Comment: Thanks @HansUp. Upgrading the format is not an option currently because the company has a large install base still using the very old format (unknown to the customers!). The code is currently using DAO to check for zero-length strings using `DAO.TableDef(fieldName).AllowZeroLength = True`. They are trying to move to ODBC or OleDB. Have also tried using `ALTER TABLE` to add the constraint, but this throws an exception too. Looks like you are right that this ancient `MS Access` does not support the modern `CHECK` constraint. Note that I am using the Jet 4.0 engine.